# running tasks in parallel as well writing to single file

Tags: xargs, gnu-parallel

```
#!/bin/bash
  range=$(seq -f "ma%04g" 5001 5505)
  for n in $range;do
      ping -q -c 1 -w 3 -s 10 $n >/dev/null
      if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
          awk -F, -v key="${n}" -v val="up" -v OFS="," '$1==key{$2=val}' /tmp/master.csv > /tmp/temptest.csv
          cp /tmp/temptest.csv /tmp/master.csv
      else
          awk -F, -v key="${n}" -v val="down" -v OFS="," '$1==key{$2=val}' /tmp/master.csv > /tmp/temptest.csv
          cp /tmp/temptest.csv /tmp/master.csv
  done
```

Not sure if I raised same query anywhere in this forum but just wondering how can I speed up this process with xargs or parallel so that I get the results. Also will it makes the /tmp/master.csv file empty?

Answer (score 2):

Gnu `parallel` would be easily able to run the loop, however, you shouldn't modify the CSV file at each iteration. It's better to collect the output into a new file and then merge it into the existing CSV, or just write the whole new CSV file from scratch if you don't have node-specific data in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
do_one() {
  n="$1"
  if ping -q -c 1 -w 3 -s 10 $n >/dev/null ; then
      echo up
  else
      echo down
  fi
}
export -f do_one
seq -f "ma%04g" 5001 5505 | parallel -j0 --tag do_one {} > results
# results contains host \t up_or_down
# create files with only hostnames for up
grep up   results | awk -e '{print $1}' > up-hosts
# create files with only hostnames for down
grep down results | awk -e '{print $1}' > down-hosts
# This perl script takes 1 second to run if you have 100000 hosts
perl -i.bak -ape 'BEGIN {
        # make fast lookup hash for up/down hosts
        chomp(@up=`cat up-hosts`);
        @up{@up} = @up;
        chomp(@down=`cat down-hosts`);
        @down{@down} = @down;
      }
      sub updown {
        my $host = shift;
        my $last = shift;
        if($up{$host}) { return "$host up" };
        if($down{$host}) { return "$host down" };
        return "$host $last";
      }
      # $1 = hostname, $2 = up/down of master.csv
      s/^(\S+)\s+(\S+)/updown($1,$2)/gme;' master.csv
```

Comment: master.csv
"node state core memory site
ma5001 up 72 128 london
ma5002 down 40 64 goa"